# Obtain property name within anonymous function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, methods, anonymous-function

Is it possible to get the name of the property that called the anonymous function in javascript?

### Example

```
var obj = {
     WhoAmI: function() {
       //Obtain the name WhoAmI
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function has no *(direct)* idea what the name of the property or variable is that references it.

Though depending on the means of invocation, it could be discovered.

```
var obj = {
     WhoAmI: function func() {
         for (var p in this)
             if (this[p] === func)
                 alert(p);
     }
}

obj.WhoAmI();
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/wUdNf/

This only works if the function is invoked with its `this` set as the object referencing it.

You could use `arguments.callee` instead of giving the function a name, though that's not permitted in *strict mode*.

Comment: So by giving the anonymous function a name we can discover it.

Comment: I should add that now after finding the answer. I may as well just do var methodName="WhoAmI" Would be easier.

Comment: Yes, if the function doesn't actually need to dynamically discover itself, then you might as well hardcode the name. If the purpose of holding the name is to invoke the function again, then just hardcode a reference to the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = {
    WhoAmI: function() {
        for (var prop in this){
            if (this[prop] === arguments.callee){
                console.log(prop);  // => 'WhoAmI'
            }
        }
    }
}

obj.WhoAmI();
```

Comment: True, but it's the only way to achieve the solution without editing the function declaration as written by the OP..I think!